# Android app crashing after I put in a seekbar [kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, seekbar

I am currently working on an android app for a school project. I have an activity, and I am trying to get a media player to work on it. I have a button to play and pause the media player, as well as a seekbar that follows along with the progress of the audio file currently playing. The user can also slide the seekbar to change the current point in the audio file.

Right now, I can get the audio to play, and the seekbar working as well, but for some reason my app is now crashing whenever I leave the activity that has the media player and seekbar in it. This happens whether or not I click the button or use the seekbar.
The problem does appear to be caused by the seekbar, however, as when I comment out only the seekbar code, the app doesn't crash anymore. Here is the code I am using:

```
class DescriptionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

//audio variables
private lateinit var audioPlayer: MediaPlayer
private lateinit var audioSlider: SeekBar
var seekHandler = Handler()
var wasPlaying = false


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_description)

    //creates the media player and slider objects
    audioPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.reitz1)
    var time = 0
    audioSlider = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.audioSeekBar)

    //looks for when the seekbar is used
    audioSlider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            //Gets the length of the current audio file
            seekBar.setMax(audioPlayer.getDuration() / 1000)

            if(fromUser) {
                audioPlayer.seekTo(progress * 1000)
            }
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
            if (audioPlayer.isPlaying() == true) {
                audioPlayer.pause()
            }
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
            if (wasPlaying == true) {
                audioPlayer.start()
            }
        }
    })


    seekUpdate()


    val playButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.playAudio)
    playButton.setOnClickListener {
        audioPlayer.isLooping = false
        if (audioPlayer.isPlaying() == true) {
            playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_audio_play)
            time = audioPlayer.getCurrentPosition()
            audioPlayer.pause()
            wasPlaying = false
        } else if (audioPlayer.isPlaying() == false) {
            playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_audio_pause)
            audioPlayer.seekTo(time)
            audioPlayer.start()
            wasPlaying = true
        }
    }


}




//audio functions
var run:Runnable = object:Runnable {
    public override fun run() {
        seekUpdate()
    }
}

fun seekUpdate() {
    audioSlider.setProgress(audioPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000)
    seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000)
}


override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    audioPlayer.stop()
    audioPlayer.release()
}

}
```

Any clue what the problem could be? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you please include the logcat trace in your question so that we see where the exception is occurring...

Answer (score 0):

One clue may be, that in `onProgressChanged` in `SeekBarOnChangeListener` `audioPlayer.getDuration()` is called after `audioPlayer.release()` - but since your code is quite incomplete...

Maybe you could try to reset the `SeekBarOnChangeListener` before releasing the `MediaPlayer`